# How to convert SQL with WHERE clause as subquery to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

```py
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(50))
    
    posts_to_tags = relationship(
        "PostsToTags", back_populates="post", cascade="all,delete")
```

```py
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tag = Column((String(50)), index=True)

    posts_to_tags = relationship(
        "PostsToTags", back_populates="tag", cascade="all,delete")
```

```py
class PostsToTags(Base):

    __tablename__ = "posts_to_tags"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(
        "posts.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True)
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="posts_to_tags")

    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(
        "tags.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True)
    tag = relationship("Tag", back_populates="posts_to_tags")
```

My attemp:

```py
        q = session.query(Post)
        if tags:
            tag_id_list = []
            for tag in tags:
                tag = session.query(Tag).filter(Tag.tag == tag).first()
                tag_id_list.append(tag.id)

            q = q.join(PostsToTags, Post.id == PostsToTags.post_id)

            q = q.filter(PostsToTags.tag_id.in_(tag_id_list))
```

I need to create an empty array in python to store `tag_id_list`. I know it's not a best, because in MYSQL. It's very clear:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.title, p.body, p.created_at
FROM posts p INNER JOIN posts_to_tags ptt ON p.id = ptt.post_id
WHERE 
    (
    SELECT t.tag
    FROM tags t
    WHERE t.id = ptt.tag_id
    )
IN ("animal", "people")
```

And I can't understand in SQL query. There duplicate with some posts which have both tags: ("animal", "people")

But in my code. There no duplicate!:

For example:

- John - #people
- Peter - #people
- Dog - #animal
- Cat - #animal
- John Tiger - #people #animal

Then with my code in Python:

tags = ["people", "animal"] ->result: John, Peter, Dog, Cat, John Tiger

And with SQL query:

tags = ["people", "animal"] ->result: John, Peter, Dog, Cat, John Tiger, John Tiger

So "John Tiger" duplicate.

So my question:

- What is the reason of different results
- The best way to write SQLAlchemy which don't have to create empty array. I try something like subquery but because of miss understanding, I can't write the good code without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already done the hard work in setting up the ORM, use it to your advantage.

Something like this should get you the correct posts:

```
tags = ["people", "animal"]
q = (
    session.query(Post)
    .where(
        Post.posts_to_tags.any(
            PostToTags.tag.has(
                Tag.tag.in_(tags)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Also look up [association tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406808/flask-sqlalchemy-difference-between-association-model-and-association-table-fo). Your `PostToTags` table can be made invisible, so that you can directly access `Post.tags` as a relationship.

Comment: I get an error     `self.db.query(Post).where(Post.posts_to_tags).any(
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'any'`

Comment: Oh I fixed: `any`->`filter` and It's work

Comment: Can you explain why. There no duplicate here?. Even when "John Tiger" check tag #people -> True. Check tag #animal -> True

Comment: I'm not an SQL expert, but with joins you have to be careful as they can return duplicate data. The way I did it is super basic, it just checks which posts match any conditions via subqueries.

Comment: Also I had a bug in my code around the `all`, if you try it again it should work :)